# entity framework wrong order of child object after some child objects detached

Tags: entity-framework

my problem is after first child object detached and then i add another child object to my parentObj the order of attached child is not correct
, my code look like this:

```
parentObj= new TparentObj();
firstChildObj=new Tchild1();
secondChildObj= new Tchild1();
thirdChildObj=new Tchild1();

parentObj.Tchild1.add(firstChildObj);
parentObj.Tchild1.add(secondChildObj);
// now parentObj.Tchild1.first()==firstChildObj return true
///then for some reason
parentObj.Tchild1.remove(firstChildObj);
db.Entry(firstChildObj).State = EntityState.Detached;

// now i add third childObj  
parentObj.Tchild1.add(thirdChildObj);
//// now parentObj.Tchild1.first()==thirdChildObj return true!!
```

after saved db the result in database is Correct;
but how can i get list of childObj in order they added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework by default uses `HashSets` for its collections. `HashSet` doesn't take ordering into account.

You shouldn't rely on the ordering of elements for it. The current implementation seems (as you are experiencing) to add the element on the first unused position (in your case, the removed one), but this is an implementation detail and you shouldn't rely on it.

About `HashSet`, [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) says about it (bold is mine):

> The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, **and whose elements are in no particular order**.

and

> **A HashSet collection is not sorted** and cannot contain duplicate elements. If order or element duplication is more important than performance for your application, consider using the List class together with the Sort method.

Comment: thanks, but how identity id field in database is in correct order? i mean thirdChildObj saved after secondChildObj

Comment: The `id` has absolutely nothing to do with the order of the elements in the collection (or the implementation of `First()`, for the matter)

Comment: you mean after i call  db.SaveChanges() , the order of ChildObjects in Database(for this parentObj) are random,
and have no relation with order they added to parentObj in program? Thank you for your patience ;)

Comment: They **may** have relation with the order you added them to `parentObj`, but not *necesarily* with the order they have in the `parentObj.Tchild1` collection. If using proxies for example, everytime you add or remove an item to a collection (which would be an `EntityCollection` then) it gets internally added to a changeset, and to the `Local` collection in your `DbSet`, and that's the order in which it'll be inserted in the database when doing `SaveChanges`. Again, that's implementation dependant and you shouldn't rely on it. If you have the need to sort, then sort by something: use `OrderBy`.